# How to Reinstall (all) Language Package(s)

Tags: keyboard, language-support, dead-keys

In my current instance of `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, I have a *bug* of not having the `English Intl with Dead Keys` option in the Language packages (in my VM it actually *does* appear) and I haven't been able to find it anywhere, be it from the `+` sign or any other advanced settings.

The steps I took to encounter this problem were:

> Go to the `Region and Language Settings`, press the `+` sign, click on
>   `English (US)` (I've also tried it with other English countries),
>   choose `English (US, intl. with dead keys)`.

Is there a way of reinstalling the English language package that includes the `Dead Keys` options for sure?

Comment: There is no English language pack which provides keyboard layouts. The layouts are provided by the `xkb-data` package. But I suspect that you misunderstand the GUI somehow. Please edit your question and explain step by step how you reached the conclusion that your desired layout isn't there.

Comment: Go to the `Region and Language Settings`, press the `+` sign, click on `English (US)` (I've also tried it with other English countries), choose `English (US, intl. with dead keys)`.

Comment: Just did. That way I successfully added it to the list of available keyboard layouts. Not sure what the problem is. Don't you know how to switch to it, so it becomes the layout in use? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: I'm not 100% sure your solution will work all the time, but it worked for me. If you wish, you can add a normal answer and I will grant you the points.

Comment: Which problem did I solve? ;) If you figured it out, I would suggest that you submit an answer yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. Then, in a couple of days, you'll be able to approve it.

Comment: After executing `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true`, *English, intl. with dead keys* does appear as a layout option. It's a bit different than the one I'm used to on Windows, but it's much better than having to keep switching layouts all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gunnar Hjalmarsson mentioned, you can add hidden layouts by using:

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources
```

which comes from this [Ubuntu Help Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html). After executing that command on a terminal, hopefully, the layout should appear for you.

Comment: Hmm.. _English (US, intl., with dead keys)_ is a widely used layout which should be available whether `show-all-sources` is enabled or not. I suspect that it was a co-incidence that it started to work for you after you had run that command.

Comment: Maybe... I don't know. We will have to wait for someone to have the same issue and have a different outcome.